# Python dataframe filling

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Good morning, I'm having a big data failure problem in my `df`. I need to find the `CO2` value similar to another time using conditions I can not do with the line information. I have a 1-year df, with values every `30 minutes`. The values of `Temperature` and `Radiation` have no missing, I only have missing values in `CO2`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_hdf('./dados.hd5')

df.head()

Year_DoY_Hour          Temperatura    radiacao        CO2
2016-01-01 00:00:00    22.44570        0              380
2016-01-01 00:30:00    22.445700       0              390 
.
.
2016-01-15 00:00:00    22.88300        0              379
2016-01-15 00:30:00    22.445700       0              381 
2016-01-15 01:00:00    22.388300       0              NaN
.
.
.
2016-01-30 00:00:00    22.400000       0              350       
2016-01-30 00:30:00    16.393900       0              375                
2016-01-30 01:00:00    17.133900       0              365
```

(a) Temperature must be between `+- 2.5 ° C`;
(b) Radiation `+- 50W / m²`;

I have to have a window of `-+ 3 days` between the value with NaN of `CO2`.

Calculate the mean of the `CO2` values when `(a)` and `(b)` are accepted in the condition and place where I have the missing `CO2` data. In the df above we have that for the day and time `2016-01-15 01:00:00` we have NaN in the `CO2` and then I can not find a `temperature` and `radiation` to fill the value of `CO2`. I believe that with conditions I can do it, but I can not.

Comment: I can't really tell what you are trying to do from the title and your description. Are you trying to fill NaN values in `CO2`? Or are you trying to find lines that meet a specific condition? If so can you please try and write that expression as a boolean expression? For example, radiation > 0.002 and temperature < 23.6.

Comment: I'm trying to fill CO2 NaN values with conditions.

Comment: Show us your code you have so far

Comment: I don't have a good code.